# Java Generics Pass .class Reference

Tags: java, generics

I need to call a super constructor that requires me to pass a `.class` reference of a generic type. How can I achieve this with Java?

The constructor wants to have..

```
Class<List<MyType>>
```

As generics are erased at runtime, I have no clue how to satisfy the constructor.

```
List<MyType>.class // does not work ;-)
```

Comment: Oh I guess now I found the answer on Stackoverflow.. Hope there is a cleaner solution then (Class<List<Object>>)(Class<?>)List.class

Comment: Unfortunately, that's as good as it gets with Java's `Class` type and generics...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this (cast to the `Class` raw type first):

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
Class<List<MyType>> clazz = (Class) List.class
```

Comment: Thanks, sad this is seems to be the way to do it :(

Comment: @chris1069603: Actually, you don't need both casts. Using the raw type cast should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the constructor for `List<MyType>`, in fact you can't call the constructor for `List` as its an interface. What you can do is call the constructor for `ArrayList.class` and also pass the type of the elements you expect.

```
public C createCollection(Class<? extends Collection> collectionClass, Class elementClass, int number) {
    Collecton c = (Collection) collectionClass.newInstance();
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
       c.add(elementClass.newInstance());
    return (C) c;
}

List<MyType> list = createCollection(ArrayList.class, MyType.class, 100);
```