# Constructor with generic class is undefined

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

I'm stuck with a stupid problem I do not understand.

```
class Foo<T extends Collection<E>, E> {
  private Class<T> collectionClass;
  private Class<E> elementClass;

  public Foo(Class<T> collectionClass, Class<E> elementClass) {
       this.collectionClass = collectionClass;
       this.elementClass = elementClass;
  }
}
```

When I try to run this

```
Foo<Collection<String>, String> foo = 
    new Foo<Collection<String>, String>(
        Collection.class,
        String.class);
```

I get a compiler error

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor Foo<Collection<String>,String>(Class<Collection>, Class<String>) is undefined
```

Why ? If I erase generics, it's ok

```
Foo foo = 
    new Foo(
        Collection.class,
        String.class);
```

If somebody has an idea, it will be great and stop me to bang my head on wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `Collection<String>.class`, is the problem.  Your alternatives include

- don't use reflection; why are you using reflection?
- accept the need for an unsafe cast
- use one of the various tools for referring to generic types at runtime, such as Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html)

Comment: Finally I refactored my API to avoid such need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do about it. Just cast around it

```
new Foo<Collection<String>, String>(
    (Class<Collection<String>>)(Class<?>)Collection.class,
    String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

No luck, because of type erasure, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050626/java-generics-pass-class-reference).

However a raw collection class and an element class may be used to generate a type safe `Collection<String>` object. So remove the redundance of E in Collection, as Collection.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you can probably relax constructor parameter type

```
public Foo(Class<?> collectionClass, Class<E> elementClass) 
{
    this.collectionClass = (Class<T>)collectionClass;
    this.elementClass = elementClass;
}

Foo<Collection<String>, String> foo = new Foo<>(Collection.class, String.class);
```

There's less type checking, so the user must make sure a wrong class is not passed in, like

```
Foo<Set<String>, String> foo = new Foo<>(List.class, String.class);
    ^^^                                  ^^^^
```

Comment: hopefully the danger of uncheck casts is contained, since the wrong code would be too obvious.

Comment: The contexts in which wrong code is obvious to a reasonable degree of probability is small.

Comment: seems fine for this constructor; wrong usages will be obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I have looked at other peoples' answers and not being the best at this...

In the Oreilly Tiger book (for version 5) (p167), they make a very explicit statement that a constructor **CAN NOT** have a wildcard in it's signature...